# Predicate not working as supposed to

Tags: prolog

```
list_trawler([44|_],_).
list_trawler([H|T],[H|T1]) :-
    list_trawler(T,T1).
```

This predicate is supposed to take two lists (say "hello, world" and "hello") and return true if the second list is the first members of the first list until there is a comma ([44]). However, although it almost works, it returns the list AND _G395. I want to get rid of the _G395.

For example,

```
2 ?- list_trawler("hello, world",X).
X = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111|_G395] 
3 ?- list_tralwer([43,78,12,90,44,12,67,98],X).
Correct to: "list_trawler([43,78,12,90,44,12,67,98],X)"? yes
X = [43, 78, 12, 90|_G30] ;
false.
```

What is wrong with the predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the `_G395` because of the `_` argument in your base case:

```
list_trawler([44|_], _).
```

This says, *"trawling" any list that starts with a comma (regardless of what the tail is) is "whatever" (I don't care).* You would probably agree that is not an accurate statement. The `_` is a "don't care" term which isn't what you really mean in the second argument. You care very much what the second argument is in this case. I think, from your description, that you want it to be the empty list.

So your base case should be:

```
list_trawler([44|_], []).   % Ignore everything after comma
```

This says that, in the base case, *"trawling" any list that starts with a comma (regardless of what the tail is) is an empty list.*

Then:

```
| ?- list_trawler("hello, world", L).

L = [104,101,108,108,111] ? ;

no
```

Similarly:

```
| ?- list_trawler("hello, world", "hello").

true ? a

no
```

And:

```
| ?- list_trawler([43,78,12,90,44,12,67,98],X).

X = [43,78,12,90] ? a

no
```